# Wordpress file permissions broken after updating php56w from 5.6.31 to 5.6.35

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, fastcgi

Last Friday, I updated my Wordpress blog's php install from php 5.6.31 to php 5.6.35. The blog is using FastCGI and Apache to serve traffic and the server is running CentOS 7. Since the upgrade, Wordpress file permissions seem to be broken. I cannot upload files to blog entries, update plugins, or update Wordpress itself.

At first, attempting to upgrade Wordpress prompted me for FTP credentials, which I had never used in the past. So I added `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` to my wp-config.php. That made progress, but I'm getting errors that imply file permissions issues, even though as far as I can tell, they are correct.

All files for wordpress are in `/var/www/html`, which is owned by `apache:apache`. Files are largely 0644 and folders are 0755, and none of them have changed since the update. httpd is running as apache, as is php-fpm. Attempting to update wordpress itself shows:

```
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-4.9.5-no-content.zip…

Unpacking the update…


Warning: copy(/var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/update-core.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 243
The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.: wp-admin/includes/update-core.php

Installation Failed
```

I am wondering if somehow the php upgrade may have changed the php config and as such broke how php accesses the blog. It doesn't seem like its a file permissions thing, although every error suggests that it is. For example, I can `sudo -u apache touch /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/test` just fine.

This is what my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` looks like:

```
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>

#AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php

#
# Uncomment the following line to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
# files as PHP source code:
#
#AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

#
# Apache specific PHP configuration options
# those can be override in each configured vhost
#
php_value session.save_handler "files"
php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session"
#php_value soap.wsdl_cache_dir  "/var/lib/php/wsdlcache"
```

Here is the yum transaction:

```
Updated php56w-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64          @webtatic
Update         5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64          @webtatic
Updated php56w-bcmath-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64   @webtatic
Update                5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64   @webtatic
Updated php56w-cli-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64      @webtatic
Update             5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64      @webtatic
Updated php56w-common-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64   @webtatic
Update                5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64   @webtatic
Updated php56w-dba-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64      @webtatic
Update             5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64      @webtatic
Updated php56w-devel-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64    @webtatic
Update               5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64    @webtatic
Updated php56w-fpm-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64      @webtatic
Update             5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64      @webtatic
Updated php56w-gd-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64       @webtatic
Update            5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64       @webtatic
Updated php56w-intl-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64     @webtatic
Update              5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64     @webtatic
Updated php56w-mbstring-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64 @webtatic
Update                  5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64 @webtatic
Updated php56w-mcrypt-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64   @webtatic
Update                5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64   @webtatic
Updated php56w-opcache-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64  @webtatic
Update                 5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64  @webtatic
Updated php56w-pdo-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64      @webtatic
Update             5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64      @webtatic
Updated php56w-process-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64  @webtatic
Update                 5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64  @webtatic
Updated php56w-soap-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64     @webtatic
Update              5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64     @webtatic
Updated php56w-xml-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64      @webtatic
Update             5.6.35-1.w7.x86_64      @webtatic
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to I could attempt to troubleshoot this if it is in fact caused by a config change caused by a php upgrade? Unfortunately, yum history undo [x] is not working for me so I think I may need to figure this out the hard way.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by SELinux. sudo setenforce permissive fixed the issue, so I will need to fix the policy.